Cycling desktop wallpapers on Debian
Solution - https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4812/wallpaper-switcher/
Solution - Scaling options can be found in 'Tweaks' applicaton
Is there any easy way to cycle through a folder full of desktop wallpapers on Debian 12 bookworm?
I have the following gnome shell extensions if that helps? Arc Menu, Just Perfection and Dash to Panel
Also is there any capacity built in to Debian to resize wallpapers? Like Ubuntu having tile, zoom, center, scale, fill, span etc.

Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/a/4500/1605405 and https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/desktop-background.html.en

Ubuntu and Debian use the same desktop environments, so there's no difference between them, because the distros themselves aren't concerned with that. You might be using different desktop environments! You mention gnome, are you using that on both platforms? Is it the same version? I wonder, because Gnome has had a pretty comprehensive background selection settings field since I think the early 2000s, so not finding settings to adjust wallpaper scaling/tiling sounds very surprising to me.

Thanks for the reply. Yeah I looked around for ages and closest I found was in 'Tweaks' and it does have scaling options. I just found a shell extension:   https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4812/wallpaper-switcher/    So I'll give that a whirl and hope it doesn't break anything. Thanks for the clarification on Debian and Ubuntu using the same desktop environments. Would you say GNOME is one of the more popular environments across all the flavours of Linux?

you don't need any extensions for that, honestly

yes, Gnome is probably the most common default environment. followed by KDE, and then there's a lot of alternatives that are smaller but still popular (MATE, Cinnamon, XFCE4), Solutions that you find on exactly one distro, and niche solutions for special needs.
